# Bootstrap dropdown giving glitch with inner CSS style

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I built a header using bootstrap. But, when I use a inner stylesheet on that page for other elements the dropdown has a glitch. Doing Upper lower bootstrap CDN or jQuery CDN link doesn't fix my problem. Header only works whenever there is not inner stylesheet or external stylesheet link. How can I solve this problem?

This is the problem I am facing right now

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/99ojl83LGJB9ezTLFb)

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, TO Bootstrap dropdown giving glitch with inner CSS style

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.